# result page should appear in different frame in struts2

Tags: struts2

my main web page contains two frames i.e. leftframe and rightframe. The rightframe includes action.jsp which will invoke the action to execute. The result page is appearing on same rightframe. How can i make it to appear in leftframe. is there any parameter for result tag in struts.xml to set this??

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding and knowledge there is no such way to set this in the struts.xnl file..you have to make it appear in your own logical way.